# bean value show correctly, but add logic in jsp and it fails

Tags: spring, jsp

The property is set in the bean, updated in the DAO, and appears correctly in the jsp when set as the following:

```
<html:hidden property="user.strInfoLocked" value="${user.strInfoLocked}" />
```

When I use developer tools, the value shows as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user.strInfoLocked" value="true">
```

But I can't get the value to be used in a conditional statement. I've tried this:

```
<c:choose>
        <c:when test="${user.strInfoLocked eq 'true'}">TRUE </c:when>
        <c:when test="${user.strInfoLocked eq 'false'}">FALSE </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

and I've tried this:

```
<c:if test= "${user.strInfoLocked == 'true'}">
     <p>My value is TRUE<p>
</c:if>
<c:if test= "${user.strInfoLocked == 'false'}">
     <p>My value is FALSE<p>
</c:if
```

and in both cases, the whole thing is skipped.

Do I need to declare this somewhere else, apart from the bean? It's just odd that the values are showing up correctly, but then when I add it to logic, the whole thing goes bezerk.

Comment: did you include [jstl] taglib and its jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both eq and == should work. I suggest you display the value from user.strInfoLocked and be sure that it has the value 'true' or 'false'.

Boolean should work, too, if you define the field in your bean as boolean.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${result.strInfoLocked}">Locked</c:when>
    <c:when test="${!result.strInfoLocked}">Not Locked</c:when>
</c:choose>
```

I have tested the code as a string and as a boolean. Both work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a type. You missed out space before eq in below statement and you need eq for the same:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${user.strInfoLockedeq 'true'}">TRUE </c:when>
    <c:when test="${user.strInfoLockedeq 'false'}">FALSE </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Chnage it to :

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${user.strInfoLocked}">TRUE </c:when>
    <c:when test="${user.strInfoLocked}">FALSE </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Oops. ..  typo in my question .. .. fixed. Sorry about that!

Comment: will do, but this isn't the answer. It was a typo here in the post, not in my code, so it still doesn't work. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Did you do the change as without any == or eq? Also you dont need quotes before and after true or false.

Comment: The value is set as a string, not a boolean. I'd tried the boolean before and got issues, so used as a string instead. In both cases, I can get the value, but the minute I add logic, I can't seem to access the value. I can't even get it to print with a c:out.